# Looking for biographical information about R. Avraham Halevi Fattal

Tags: history, rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, hacham-ovadia-yosef

I'm writing something for which I need a capsule biography of him. So far, about all I know is:

- He is the father-in-law of (יבלח"ט) R. Ovadiah Yosef.
- He was an important figure in the Syrian Jewish community in Jerusalem.
- He passed away on 19 Tammuz 5741.

Anyone know where else I can find useful information?

Comment: I don't know about the reliability of http://familytrees.genopro.com/RaymondM/default.htm?page=FATTAL-Avraham-ind01991.htm, and it doesn't have much info, but it may help some. It indicates some other family members' names and dates. (To find the _rishon l'tziyon_, follow the hyperlinks through Zhiya and Margalit.)

Comment: @msh210, thanks. However, it doesn't have R. Avraham's own dates.

Comment: there's a picture of Ovadya Yosef with his father-in-law in this publication: http://www.sephardiclegacy.com/pdf/June2010Yosef.pdf

Comment: @Scimonster if you are interested in keeping off-topic questions closed, consider voting on this [meta post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/262/the-parameters-of-jewish-life-scope). Note my favorite answers: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4077/8775 and http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4076/8775.

Answer (score 3):

He wrote a book about of divrei Torah on parachat hachavoua. I think it's entitled *Vayaan Avraham* or *Vayomer Avraham*. Maybe there is a biography as introduction.

Bli neder, I will check it this Chabbat in my shul.

Chabbat chalom.

Comment: It's Vayomer Avraham. I think I looked in it and didn't find anything, but I don't recall; so yes, if you find anything, that would help.

Comment: @Alex, sorry for the delay. I had a look on the first volume and there is a little biography at the beginning (approx. 6 pages).

Answer (score 3):

In the introduction to Va'yomer Avraham, there is the following information:

- His middle name was "Moshe"
- His father was "Chacham Moshe ben Siti"
- His first wife was "Zechiah bat Mazal"
- He mentions another woman, possibly a second wife, "Sultana bat Cheftzi-Bah"
- He had a son "Avigdor" who died young

There is also a picture of him in the book.

Comment: His middle name was his father's name?

Comment: @DoubleAA That is not unknown among some groups of sephardim, I understand specifically Moroccans.

Comment: Welcome to the site, user3361, and thanks for your answer. Bibliographic info on the book you're citing would much improve your answer: you can [edit] it right in. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site! (You may also wish to [change your username](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/3361), unless you're attached to the number 3361.)